# Best way to handle the time taken by BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: spring-security, bcrypt

So I'm working on a web application which involves saving user credentials in the database. To encrypt password I'm using BCryptPasswordEncoder from spring security. The encoder understandably takes long time to encrypt the password (similarly during password match also). My question is what's the best way to handle this time taking process..for e.g. should I do the encryption asynchronously and return to user immediately or return the next only after password encryption is complete?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Here're some stats: with length parameter 20 the time taken was around 7 seconds, with parameter being 16 time taken was 5 sec, with 12 it was close to 3 sec, and with default value which is 10 it 1.42 sec.

Comment: Doing it asynchronously doesn't sound like a good idea. You need to do the same work when you authenticate anyway. Pick a value which is acceptable for your users and use that. Alternatively, you can maybe invest in faster hardware.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I agree that's why I finally settled on the default value of 10.